# How to use multiple themes at the same time

Tags: themes, xpages

I'm looking for a way to use multiple themes in one XPages application, each theme active in a different section of the application. For instance to support an single .nsf application with both a public facing website (custom theme) and a CMS with a OneUI theme.

You can set which theme is used through the whole application on the XPage Properties tab in Application Properties. It's also possible to change the theme for a user's session with this code:

```
context.setSessionProperty("xsp.theme", <theme_id>)
```

But both options set the theme for *all* pages in the current .nsf, and I'm looking for a way to specify theme X for one part of the application and theme Y for a second part.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

On any page that should use an alternate theme, use the following syntax to apply the property directly to the view root:

```
<xp:view>
<xp:this.properties>
<xp:parameter name="xsp.theme" value="alternateThemeName" />
</xp:this.properties>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cheered to early, I can't get it to work. This are the first 9 lines of the XPage: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
 xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
 xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
 <xp:this.properties>
  <xp:parameter
   name="xsp.theme"
   value="oneuiv2.1" />
 </xp:this.properties>
I can't see a difference in the page. What could it be that I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like this is one of the properties that can't be set directly against the view root. I'm looking into this and will let you know what I find.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all of the above, but none of them worked for me. But I found a solution:

Paste this into the view's beforeRenderResponse event:

```
context.setSessionProperty("xsp.theme", "yourAlternateThemeName")
```

There is one issue: once you have used this way you have to use it always and on every page as this sets a session property which is stored as long as you are logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Just talked with colleague Tony Mcguckin.

You can change the theme per page. Under all properties of the XPage select data-properties and create a new property with name "xsp.theme" and value "yourThemeName".

Comment: Hi Niklas, thanks for you reply. If I'm correct this is the same as Tim Tripcony's answer and I couldn't get that to work. I tried this approach (via the GUI) also, but still no results.

Answer (score 1):

While I like the idea of having page-specific themes, based on the specific use case you're describing, the "right" way to do this is to have two separate XPage applications bound to the same back end data store. Not only does this make it simple to specify a different theme for each, it also simplifies the ACL (assuming you'll have different people accessing the public site vs. the CMS), makes it easier to tune performance by having different settings per application, and even without having application-specific settings, should improve performance slightly just because of Java class loader behavior: each NSF acts as a distinct ClassLoader, and each XPage or Custom Control in your NSF results in the storage of a separate class file. So, in theory, if the features of your public site require you to create 5 XPages and the CMS features span 10 XPages, simply splitting these into two separate apps makes it easier for the class loader to retrieve the class for any page a user loads, because it doesn't have to ignore the classes it will never need for that user just to find the one class it does need at the time. So I'm still tempted to find a way to get page-specific themes working just for the "cool" factor of it, but for this specific purpose, I'd recommend using two different applications entirely, with a different theme assigned to each.

Comment: I understand your point and appreciate it. There's always the choice to keep everything in one DB or to split things up. In this case the choice to keep everything in one DB was easy. The ease of maintenance and setup is more important than ultimate performance or "doing things the right way"(TM). There are just 3 XPages in the CMS (at the moment) and it's an action-site that will run for only 3 months. After that it will be archived and a new copy will be started. So it's a huge pre to have it on just one DB.

Comment: In that case, I agree: the incremental performance improvement from the UI segregation likely wouldn't even be noticeable if the CMS features only require 3 XPage elements. I'm going to keep playing with the page-specific theme idea as time permits just because I agree that it would be cool to get working.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that much about themes but cant you check in your theme (with some ssjs) at which viewroot ( by id? ) you are and according to that include the correct styles , css and other resources?