# How to load a different theme for a single Xpage

Tags: xpages

Before I begin, this has been asked before, *but* none of the answers were accepted, and I was not able to get it to work using the answers provided. [How to use multiple themes at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367722/how-to-use-multiple-themes-at-the-same-time)

I am trying to use a dojoTreeGrid which requires a theme that "extends webstandard" but when I do this, I fix the tree grid, but it breaks many other parts of the application.  Webstandard seems to conflict badly with Bootstrap.

I cloned my theme and added the "extends webstandard" to the clone, and then want to load ONLY that theme on the Xpage that contains the grid.  I have tried entering a "themeID: to the properties.  I have creating a parameter of the xp:view (as suggested in the linked SO above) and no change.

How can I get the secondary theme loaded and not the main theme loaded for this one Xpage only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get the TreeGrid to pick up the tundra theme, without requiring that your application theme inherit from webstandard.

I noticed in the generated source when the theme extends webstandard that a lot of grid components have a class of "tundra" (along with other classes). When I create (and apply) an empty theme that does not inherit from webstandard, the grid components do not inherit "tundra" as a class.

Correspondingly, the page's `<body>` tag gets a class of tundra (and xspView) when webstandard is in effect, but no class otherwise.

I was able to fix the grid styling with two steps:

1) Include dojo.css (since it doesn't seem to be included when webstandard is not extended). This example loads it as a page-level resource:

```
<xp:styleSheet href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css"></xp:styleSheet>
```

2) Wrap the grid `<div>` in another `<div>` that has the "tundra" class.

```
<div class="tundra">
  <div style="width:400px; height:400px;" id="treeGrid"></div>
</div>
```

This fixed it in my demo app.

This seems ideal because it should limit the styling to the div that surrounds your grid.

Comment: This works perfect Brad for my specific issue.  Regarding the general question, both Toby and Tim are correct, and the bottom line is there is no great answer to the question.  Both will be right depending on your specific circumstance, and both will seems like too much trouble since it seems like there should be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a surprisingly easy way to accomplish this: place the other XPage in its own NSF.

I know this sounds ironic coming from me: I'm routinely telling people not to split their code into different containers just because their data lives in separate places. For example, why have 5 NSFs for a single CRM app just because, from a data architecture perspective, it might make sense to segregate contacts, accounts, interaction history, and other data into a separate NSF for each. Keep all the *code* in one place, and access *all* the data from there.

In this instance, however, why not do the reverse? If you have just one page with user interface requirements that wreak havoc on the UI of the rest of your app, why not make a separate app just for that one page? The obvious downside is that this introduces additional complexity in ensuring that the destination page has sufficient context to know where the user is coming from, how to behave as a result of that context, and how to ensure the origin app is notified of any relevant events that occurred in the other app upon the user's return... but designing this reciprocal context transfer is likely to be simpler than making every aspect of the existing app more complex just to cater to the visual needs of this one page that doesn't play well with others.

Consider third-party web apps that have been specifically designed to allow origin applications to integrate with them, including preservation of branding. For example, when you build a shopping cart on an e-commerce site, then check out using PayPal, you temporarily leave the app you were in, and now you're on PayPal's website, but the page you're now on has received some origin context -- usually not only information about the purchase itself, but also about the seller, allowing for at least some minimal branding that differs from what you would have seen had you instead been purchasing from a different seller. When you complete (or cancel) your purchase, you're back where you came from, and the origin app "knows" what occurred while you were gone.

Were you to design a similar process, then this grid page could be reused by numerous apps, each telling it upon the user's arrival how to find the data it must display, but also how to visually represent it based on where the user was coming from... and how to take them back to where they were when appropriate.

Alternatively, you could examine which deficiencies in the app's search features necessitate displaying data in a grid to begin with, but that's probably a discussion best left for another day.

Answer (score 1):

Some variation of this works, and it is listed in this other SO post.

[How to use multiple themes at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367722/how-to-use-multiple-themes-at-the-same-time/9378044#)

```
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (!"webstandard".equals(context.getSessionProperty("xsp.theme"))) {
    context.setSessionProperty("xsp.theme", "webstandard");
    context.reloadPage();
}}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

Here is the code that you would need to include to ensure a different xpage got a different theme in a phase listener.

```
package com.tobysamples.listeners;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext;

public class ThemePhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5981547066445581282L;

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {


    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {
        XSPContext context = XSPContext.getXSPContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if ((!"webstandard".equals(context.getSessionProperty("xsp.theme"))) && (context.getUrl().toString().contains("MyXpage.xsp"))) {
            context.setSessionProperty("xsp.theme", "webstandard");
            try {
                facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect((((HttpServletRequest)facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRequestURI()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

}
```

and in the faces-config.xml

```
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.tobysamples.listeners.ThemePhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
```

Comment: Problem is that this sets that theme for all pages you'll load from the .nsf after that. To reset the theme you'll have to add this code to each and every other XPage in the database and have the code reset the theme.

Comment: Exactly Thimo, I was hoping to avoid this method for that reason.

Comment: I have used this logic in a phase listener, but you will have to have a place to store which page gets which theme.

Comment: @TobySamples  My situation is where I have about 25 pages that use the primary theme, and then will have one that uses the secondary theme.  I am hoping to avoid having to change all the other pages for the one.  Is there a way to set the session property back to the primary after loading the page?  So it changes property, loads page, resets property for other pages.  Have you ever tried that?  I might give it a try.

Comment: I couldn't get my idea to work because as soon as the page is reloaded all event code after that is never run so you can't reset the theme property

Comment: If you use an application wide phase listener it will run the code in the before render response of every page, without coding it on every page.  So in your case you could just check the pageName vs your one page and if it is then reset the theme otherwise check the theme and reset it if its set back to the other.